# How to reshape a dataframe keeping unique information?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1` that contains information of interactions between agents and their status.

```
df1
     Name1   Name2  Name1_x Y_x Name1_y Y_y
0    Jack    John   Jack     0  John     1
1    Sarah   Jack   Sarah    0  Jack     0
2    Sarah   Eva    Sarah    0  Eva      1
3    Eva     Tom    Eva      1  Tom      0
4    Eva     John   Eva      1  John     1
```

I would like to have a dataframe with the name and the status `y`, such as

```
df2
     Name   Y
0    Eva    1
1    John   1
2    Tom    0
3    Sarah  0
4    Jack   0
```

Comment: @pygo I have just a dataframe

Comment: Okay,  i see the information updated.

Comment: can you explain more about the interactions  like i see initial three columns then status and thereafter one another column and status, What will be the Key to get the new desired status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.r_[df1.iloc[:,2:4], df1.iloc[:,4:6]], columns=['Name', 'Y']).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Y
0   Jack  0
1  Sarah  0
2    Eva  1
3   John  1
4    Tom  0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the most succinct way of achieving your result I can think of is the following:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.loc[:, 'Name1_x':].values.reshape(-1, 2), columns=['Name', 'Y']).drop_duplicates()
```

This produces

```
    Name  Y
0   Jack  0
1   John  1
2  Sarah  0
5    Eva  1
7    Tom  0
```

which you can sort with

```
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['Y', 'Name'], ascending=[False, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

such that the final result is

```
    Name  Y
0    Eva  1
1   John  1
2   Jack  0
3  Sarah  0
4    Tom  0
```

(I don't know why Jack appears last in your expected output, I'm assuming a typo or that it does not matter.)